# Find movement of a device

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am working on a project that requires finding the patterns made by device movement (like a golf swing for e.g.). I've searched a lot and still couldn't get any prepackaged library for this. 
Now I'm trying to build one from scratch. In order to do this, I've retrieved gyroscope data from device to find those patterns but unsuccessful so far.
These are the cases that I mentioned in a nut-shell.

- Case 1: Find the wave motion like a golf swing.
- Case 2: Plot this
  motion in a 3D plane so that user can view the motion of device.

Current source code (data from gyroscope)

```
    float[] values = event.values;

    // Movement
    float x = values[0];
    float y = values[1];
    float z = values[2];

    xAxis.setText("X : " + (int)x + " rad/s");
    yAxis.setText("Y : " + (int)y + " rad/s");
    zAxis.setText("Z : " + (int)z + " rad/s");

    boolean waveFactor = (((int)z) > 3) && (((int)x) > 1);
    if(waveFactor) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Horizontal wave success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Any sort of help/direction is well appreciated.

Comment: Please share some code you already have

Comment: Added the same @jrswgtr

Answer (score 1):

Gyroscope is not enough for your plans.  You will also need accelerometer data.    And also take into account,  that axes information from event is in coordinate system tied to device - not real world.  So you will need more sophisticated code to detect  and evaluate movement.  I did some small projects to record and display FFT analysed data from accelerometer.  Feel free to take inspiration from it.

https://github.com/ko5tik/accmeter/blob/master/src/main/java/de/pribluda/android/accmeter/Sampler.java

https://github.com/ko5tik/accanalyser